# Inject html from Component angular2

Tags: html, angular, components, inject

I need to inject html from component depends on some value.
For example if property='TEXT' I need to inject input like this:

```
<input class="form-control"
                   id="value"
                   type="{{type}}"
                   ngControl="value"
                   [(ngModel)]="newValue">
```

but if property is 'BIGTEXT' i need to inject textarea:

```
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6"
              id="value"
              ngControl="value"
              [(ngModel)]="newValue"
              value="ngForm">
    </textarea>
```

If property is 'DATE' I need to inject  etc.
Is the way to inject this to HTML without *ngIf="property == 'some'"?

Comment: Why don't you wanna use `*ngIf`? It is the usual and common way for Angular

Comment: I have problems with binding errors. I cannot make variable #value="ngForm" and form.controls['value'] didnt work.

Comment: Do you use the new or old forms module?

Comment: I am using ControlGroup, FormBuilder and Validators from @angular/common rc.1. I cannot use higher version.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code for others to be able to diagnose the problem. A Plunker would be best.